Unable to start posgtresql on AlmaLinux 8.4
I’ve been working with the database for over a year, but after rebooting the server I can’t start postgresql:
Job for postgresql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri 2024-05-24 10:51:52 +03; 44s ago
  Process: 4805 ExecStart=/usr/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
  Process: 4803 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postgresql-check-db-dir postgresql (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4805 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

# journalctl -xe

May 24 10:51:44 hitriy systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.```
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd-coredump[4808]: Resource limits disable core dumping for process 4805 (postmaster).
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd-coredump[4808]: Process 4805 (postmaster) of user 26 dumped core.
-- Subject: Process 4805 (postmaster) dumped core
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- Documentation: man:core(5)
--
-- Process 4805 (postmaster) crashed and dumped core.
--
-- This usually indicates a programming error in the crashing program and
-- should be reported to its vendor as a bug.
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- The unit postgresql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
May 24 10:51:52 hitriy systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.

Whats wrong?
Please help me!!!

There are logs in the data directory that may have more information on why the crash occurred. Add that information to the question.

didn’t find anything in the logs to indicate the reason, only this at the last work of server: `2024-05-23 00:00:09.501 +03 [1519181] WARNING:  skipping "shipments" --- only table or database owner can analyze it
